# why does my app crash when changing activities?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

 public class howActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.howto);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}
}
```

it has to be something in this program because it will switch to other activities just not this one

Comment: When you have an error, add the logcat.

Comment: You should post the caller activity, from where you call this one, the bug is probably there, unless there is some issue with howto layout.

Comment: +1 to @ZouZou.  Logcat errors would be helpful as would the code that you are using to switch activities.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your activity is clearly defined in your `Manifest` file

Comment: No problem, that Manifest gets me every time